# gufw GUI fails to launch on LMDE

Tags: nvidia, firewall, ufw, webkit

After upgrading from LMDE2 to LMDE3 Cindy I noticed I could no longer launch the gufw GUI.

The error was:

```
** (gufw.py:20536): WARNING **: Failed to load shared library 'libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37' referenced by the typelib: libGLESv2.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/usr/share/gufw/gufw/gufw/view/gufw.py:117: Warning: cannot retrieve class for invalid (unclassed) type 'void'
  self.web_content = WebKit2.WebView()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/gufw/gufw/gufw.py", line 30, in <module>
    gufw = Gufw(controler.get_frontend())
  File "/usr/share/gufw/gufw/gufw/view/gufw.py", line 79, in __init__
    self._set_objects_name()
  File "/usr/share/gufw/gufw/gufw/view/gufw.py", line 117, in _set_objects_name
    self.web_content = WebKit2.WebView()
```

gufw version is 17.04.1-1.1
ufw version is 0.35-4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In hindsight I think the problem probably had nothing to do with the upgrade, and everything to do with changing to non-free nvidia drivers. (I just hadn't needed to change any firewall settings until after the upgrade.)I checked all of the stated dependencies and everything required seemed to be installed, including libgles2-mesa and webkit2-4.0.

I installed:

libgles2-nvidia
libgles-nvidia2
libgles2-glvnd-nvidia

And was able to launch the gufw GUI.